# Facebook Open Graph - still display wrong image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, caching

My Open Graph publish action still display in the wall incorrect image. I've tried to clean cache in the browser - didn't help...

Also I've tried to empty FB OG cache this way (in the Facebook Object Debugger):

```
http://my-website.com/my-app/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
```

but got this error:

```
Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://my-website.com/my-app/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING' of type 'app_url_name:object_name' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

I'ev read that Facebook clean up the cache each 24 hours, but this is already third day...

So, how could I empty the cache, if the attempts above don't works?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your **og:url** value before the cache can be cleared.

What's the result of http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://YOUR_OBJECT_URL

(Note that it is the URL of the **Open Graph Object** you have to use.)